# Как в FPDF сделать перенос строки в ячейке таблицы?

Tags: php, fpdf

Нужно создать обычную таблицу, я делаю так:

```
    private function ListSection($width1, $width2 ,$width3 , $height)
{
    if (is_array($this->table_data)){
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
        $this->SetFillColor(150);
        $this->Cell($width1, $height, 'Student', 1, '', 'C', true);
        $this->Cell($width2, $height, 'Parent', 1, '', 'C', true);
        $this->Cell($width3, $height, 'Notes', 1, '', 'C', true);
        $this->Ln();
        $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
        foreach ($this->table_data as $td){
            $this->Cell($width1, $height, $td['STUDENT_FIRSTNAME'] . ' ' . $td['STUDENT_LASTNAME'], 1);
            $this->Cell($width2, $height, $td['PARENT_FIRSTNAME'] . ' ' . $td['PARENT_LASTNAME'], 1);
            $this->Cell($width3, $height, $td['NOTES'], 1);
            $this->Ln();
        }
    }
}
```

проблема в том что в поле `NOTES` может быть текст любой длины, и он межет выйти за пределы ячейки. Как сделать чтоб он переносился автоматически как в обычной таблице?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наверное уже не актуально, но я все же отвечу. Используйте вместо `Cell` функцию `MultiCell`. Она как раз обладает необходимыми свойствами (автоматичекским переносом строки). В остальном использование такое же, что и `Cell`